# How can I get CPU Usage with PHP on Windows IIS 8.5? (2012 R2)

Tags: php, windows, iis

What I'm looking for is an easy way to get either individual core usage or total CPU usage for the system that the PHP Script is running on.

However I'm unable to do so. I've looked all over for all manner of solutions from using perf (with and without passthru) to using winmgmts through COM.

The issue is, some of these will work on Windows if you use Apache, but with IIS the security restrictions stop PHP from being able to use for example winmgmts through COM so I just get back a null object.

How can I solve this? - I've honestly tried every solution I can find on the internet and while there is lots of information about how to raise the permissions all the guides point to IIS 7 or earlier and are no longer applicable to IIS 8.5 with literally the suggested option changes being non-existent.

If anyone could help me with this I'd be really appreciative, a workaround like using a third party application that could provide this data would also be acceptable if I can query the data through PHP either from a file or network etc Even a asp.net script that I could query? (I don't know anything about asp.net but I could use it for this single thing if it'd work?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this and I hope it helps someone else.

What you must do is convert the folder where your PHP (or asp) will execute to an Application. So the structure will look like this:

```
    Website Name
    -> Application Name
```

Then you want to select the parent folder, the Website Name folder and go to "Basic Settings" in the far right actions pane and select "Connect As..." and connect as an Administrator account.

Once you've done this the application will inherent the credentials you specified on the parent website folder and you'll now have full access to perf, wmi and so on.

If you only give the credentials directly to the application it doesn't work and it also doesn't work if you don't convert your folder where your scripts will execute to an application. This is where I was being tripped up and the documentation online is very sparse.

I'd like to thank the good people at the phpsysinfo github for their IIS documentation which pointed me on the right track on needing to convert a site to an application which was part of the puzzle I was missing.